# Necessary to declare !doctype in Joomla pages?

Tags: php, html, joomla

I'm running my website in Joomla 1.7. Now I just call to php and html pages from within Joomla (articles), I don't use the Joomla template designs. What I would like to know, is it necessary to include !doctypes such as the one below into all my php and html pages used in Joomla, or does Joomla automatically add those to all webpages?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Thank You

Comment: is this not something you can test ? ie look at the source of the response ?

Comment: No, just put it in your main template index file and it will be included on all pages. Have a look at the core templates like Beez and you will see where it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a template with your joomla application. This tamplate has a main layout which should include the `DOCTYPE`. If you create an article this should be rendered inside your layout, so you don't need to add the `DOCTYPE` there.

I hope I understood your question right, but you can even test it, if joomla doesn't add the `DOCTYPE` add it by yourself.